# No rebuild after choosing value in Dropdown

Tags: flutter

I am sending the choosen value of the DropdownMenu via Callback to the parent widget (see code below).

```
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: Text(widget.hint),
      value: valueChoose,
      items: widget.users.map((dynamic valueItem) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: valueItem,
          child: Text(valueItem),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          valueChoose = newValue;
          besetzungsList.add(valueChoose);
          widget.besetzungsListChanged(valueChoose);
          widget.fromDropDown(true);
        });
      },
    );
```

The problem is with "besetzungsList[i] = value;" no rebuild occurs. But I need the choosen value to be shown in the UI. If I set the value via the insert function then it works. But I need to replace the value inside the list.

```
  DataCell(DropDown(
                  hint: "Wählen",
                  users: users,
                  besetzungsListChanged: (String value) {
                    besetzungsList[i] = value;
                  },
                  fromDropDown: (bool value) => fromDropDown = value,
                ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the parent widget a stateful widget?

you can try to call setState in `benutzungsListChanged`to enforce rebuild of the parent widget

```
DataCell(DropDown(
    hint: "Wählen",
    users: users,
    besetzungsListChanged: (String value) {
         setState(() {besetzungsList[i] = value;});
    },
    fromDropDown: (bool value) => fromDropDown = value,
                ))
```